Trying to use a pure JSON approach to insert a JSON Element into each Element of a JSON Array
Embedded SQL can insert an Element into each Array Element, but the code feels troublesome. After adding inserting the Element into each Array member, I must CONCAT() brackets back into the output, to once again restore the Array.
Here is the SQL:
DECLARE @ArrayJSON  NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"BookName":"First Book", "Order": 1},{"BookName":"Second Book", "Order": 2}]';
DECLARE @ObjectJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Page":1,"Chapter":2}';
DECLARE @FinalJSON  NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH [ParsedOriginal] AS
  (
    SELECT [Element] = JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.Params', JSON_QUERY(@ObjectJSON)) FROM OPENJSON(@ArrayJSON)
  )
  SELECT @FinalJSON = (SELECT [Elements] = STRING_AGG([Element], ',')FROM [ParsedOriginal]);

SET @FinalJSON = CONCAT('[', @FinalJSON,']');

PRINT @@VERSION;
PRINT CONCAT('@ArrayJSON  = ',@ArrayJSON );
PRINT CONCAT('@ObjectJSON = ',@ObjectJSON);
PRINT CONCAT('@FinalJSON  = ',@FinalJSON );

And here is the output:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019

@ArrayJSON  = [{"BookName":"First Book", "Order": 1},{"BookName":"Second Book", "Order": 2}]
@ObjectJSON = {"Page":1,"Chapter":2}
@FinalJSON  = [{"BookName":"First Book", "Order": 1,"Params":{"Page":1,"Chapter":2}},{"BookName":"Second Book", "Order": 2,"Params":{"Page":1,"Chapter":2}}]

Can this solution be improved to avoid STRING functions, and rely more on JSON functions?

No you can't, there is currently no JSON_AGG function in SQL Server, although it is proposed https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753 Another option is to give OPENJSON a schema, and then just do FOR JSON as normal https://dbfiddle.uk/ZoFFYr0l A slightly simpler version of what you have is https://dbfiddle.uk/GaxrJRVD

charlieface, can you please create your response as an answer that i can approve?

Well it's not an answer other than to say "no carry on as you are doing". If/when those functions get added then an answer can be added. Unless you meant to use OPENJSON but that doesn't necessarily give the same results: you would need to specify every possible value, and null and all spacing would get stripped out. Or do you mean the slightly simpler version I mentioned, that is also not really answering how to use better functions for this.
